# shell script - assign regex to a variable based on result of an if statement

Tags: regex, shell

I have an `if` statement (which tests if a variable (`test`) has a certain value) which then assigns a value to a new variable (`result`) based on the result of the `if` statement. One of the values has got to be a regex, which will match the next item to be a letter (a-z, A-Z).

```
if [ "$test" -eq "0" ] // if test = 0
then
    result="^[a-zA-Z\-]"
fi
```

What would the regex be and how would I assign it (not sure if I'm assigning it right)?

Thanks :)

EDIT: it would be used in a sentence like structure, e.g `The next character needs to be a letter:` and `result` would make sure the next character is a letter.

Comment: How are you using `$result` variable in rest of your code?

Comment: in this instance, it would be used to match a sentence (e.g the next character should be a letter, `result` would make sure the next character is a letter). I can't really show the code, sorry.

Also do you know why this got downvoted twice?

Comment: No idea who and why down-voted it. But I think it is probably because question is not very clear and has no example values. e.g. first you wrote **regex that only matches lowercase letters** and now this: **result would make sure the next character is a letter)**

Comment: yeah I was being a bit uptight, it doesn't have to be lowercase, it's just more common that it'll be a lowercase letter. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash doesn't have any way to store a regular expression other than as a string, so yes, it's just regular string assignment, like so:

```
if next_input_must_start_with_a_letter; then
  regex='^[[:alpha:]]'
else
  regex='' # always match unconditionally
fi

read -r input
if ! [[ $input =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "Input did not match regex!" >&2
fi
```